# Trove's emblems/flasks chances

Tags: trove

Can someone who has many [emblems and flasks](http://trove.wikia.com/wiki/Vial) share **the estimations of probabilities that they will proc**?
I am especially interested in chance that Bountiful emblem doesn't consume a charge. [On Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Trove/comments/3pq07s/is_the_bountiful_emblem_broken/) is mentioned that it proced 0 times out of 115, which is < 1% probability and looks unbelievably low, so I wonder if that was a bug, which is fixed now.